# List all Wordpress key words

Tags: 404-error

I have a page

```
http://bhaa.ie/realex-ipn.php
```

that returns normally when called with GET but is throwing a 404 when it is called via a POST request

```
curl -i -X POST http://bhaa.ie/realex-ipn.php
```

I'm trying to understand what is causing the issue. I've disabled the various plugins i have installed and the issue is still there. I know that using key works as http parameter names can causes issues and that the list of [wordpress reserved keywords](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) is here.

I think it might be the case that one of my plugins has registered its own keyword and this is causing this 404 issue. Is there a way to list all the keywords that wordpress and the installed plugins have registered?

Comment: What is `realex-ipn.php`? Is it a custom page template? A non-WordPress resource? Something else? Please clarify how this question is **WordPress** related/specific.

Comment: it's a non-wordpress php. My site 'bhaa.ie' is being managed by wordpress. I believe the wordpress routing is component that is stopping the POST request making it this php file.

Comment: I get 1) an odd error page with a browser, 2) a WordPress 404 with curl + GET or curl + POST. That doesn't seem to match your description. Disable your caching plugin.

Comment: Caching plugin disabled now.

Comment: And what happens once the plugin is disabled? Do you expect us to do all of your debugging?

Comment: no change - so i'm ruling out the caching as the cause of it. I'm just looking for alternative strategies to isolating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your own `.php` files outside WordPress but you do not have WordPress' rewrite magic to support you.

If you want to load the file from `http://bhaa.ie/realex-ipn.php` that file will have to be at the root of your installation-- same directory as `license.txt`. If your file is in your theme you have to load it with a complete path such as `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/themename/realex-ipn.php`. It is still possible to have rewrite conflicts though.

This is not the best way to do this.

1. Create a WordPress "Page" for your code and [assign a custom template
   to it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template).
2. Or use the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to process the request.